# Is git pull, docker-compose build and docker-compose up -d a good way to deploy complete solution on an empty machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Recently, we just finished web application solution using Docker.

https://github.com/yccheok/celery-hello-world/tree/nginx (The actual solution is hosted in private repository. This example just a quick glance on how our project structure looks like)

We plan to purchase 1 empty Linux machine on deploy on it. We might purchase more machines in the future but with current traffic right now, 1 machine will be sufficient.

My plan for deployment on the single empty machine is

```
git pull <from private code repository>
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

Since we are going to deploy to multiple machines in near future, I was wondering, is this a common practice to deploy docker application into a fresh empty machine?

Is there anything we can utilize from https://hub.docker.com/ , without requiring us to perform `git pull` during deployment stage?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't want to perform `git pull` in each machine - your intuition is correct.

Instead you want to use remote docker registry (as docker hub for example).

So the right flow, each time your source code (git repo) is changed:

1. `git pull` from all relevant repos.
2. `docker-compose build` to build all relevant images.
3. `docker-compose push` to push all images (diff) to remote registry.
4. `docker-compose pull` in your production machines, to get the latest updated images.
5. `docker-compose up` to start all containers.

First 3 steps should be done in your CI machine (for example, as a jenkins job). Steps 4-5 in your production machines.

**EDIT**: one thing  to consider. I think build via docker-compose is bad. Consider building directly by `docker build -f Dockerfile -t repo/image:tag .` and in `docker-compose` just specify the image name.

Comment: For step 4, how can I know which services I should pull to the empty machine? Do I need to do it manually?

Comment: No, you don't have to do it manually. That's what `docker-compose pull` does for you. It's compare each of your images with those who are existing in the remote registry and if there is a newer version, he'll pull the image diffs and update it for you.

Comment: What I mean is, initially, my production machine is completely empty. My docker hub contains 10 images of 10 services. So, when I first run on production machine, I need to run `docker-compose pull service0`, `docker-compose pull service1`, ... ?

Comment: No. You don't have to specify each one of your services. The `docker-compose pull` command will do it for you. It will compare each one of the images specified in your `docker-compose.yml` file and verify that it is up to date.

Answer (score 3):

My opinion is you should not BUILD images on production machines. Because the image might be different than you would expect and you should limit yourself what you do on production machines.. With that being said, i would recommend:

1. updating the code on your local computer (development)
2. when you push code to git, you should use some software to build
   your images from your push. For example Gitlab-CI (Continuous
   integration tool)
3. gitlab-ci will build the image, then it could run some tests on that
   image, and then deploy it to production (this build image)
4. On you production machine just do `docker-compose pull &&
   docker-compose up -d` and that is it.

**I strongly recommend to build images on other machine than production machines, and use some CI tool to test your images before deploying**. For example https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/README.html

Answer (score 2):

Deploying it on a fresh machine or the other way around would be fine.
The best way to go around is to make a private repo on https://hub.docker.com/ and push your images there.

Building and shipping the image

- `git pull`
- `docker build`
- `docker login`
- `docker push repo/image`

Pulling the shipped image and deploying

- `docker login` on the server
- `docker pull repo/image`
- `docker-compose up -d`

Though i would recommend you to look at container scheduling using `kubernetes` and setting up your `CI/CD` stack with `jenkins` to automate this process, in case something bad happens it can be a life saver.